# Create deb from dvcs-source

Tags: command-line, package-management, source-code

Is there a system in Ubuntu which simplify the process of getting the sources from git, compile and package it into a deb?

I'm looking for something similar to the PKGBUILD in ArchLinux which can be configured with any kind of vcs repo as source and then packaged as that distributions package format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [git-buildpackage](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/piki/projects/git-buildpackage/).

[There are similar tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=buildpackage&searchon=names&suite=maverick&section=all), one for each VCS:

```
$ aptitude search buildpackage
p   arch-buildpackage            - tools for maintaining Debian packages using arch              
v   bzr-buildpackage             -                                                               
p   cvs-buildpackage             - A set of Debian package scripts for CVS source trees.         
p   darcs-buildpackage           - Suite to help with Debian packages in Darcs archives          
p   git-buildpackage             - Suite to help with Debian packages in Git repositories        
p   mercurial-buildpackage       - Suite to maintain Debian packages in Mercurial repository     
p   svn-buildpackage             - helper programs to maintain Debian packages with Subversion   
p   tla-buildpackage             - Suite to help with Debian packages in Arch archives
```